# LaunchScreen and Storyboard in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am New to IPhone Development.I am Creating a sample app to just know how to make Iphone apps. I came across Launch screen and Storyboard in the project Description, But was not able to understand what is the role of launch screen and Storyboard.Can anyone plz explain briefly about both. Can i Delete LaunchScreen.xib from my project.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Screen is always first screen of your app. Also according to apple, "You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6."

While in Storyboard you create rest of your applications screens.

For more info about Launch Screen refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)
And Storyboarding is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html).

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 3):

1. See ***Launch Screen*** is something in which you can use that as
   **Splash Screen** or ***Start Screen*** for your application.
2. In ***StoryBoard*** only you can create all the **front end** functionality of your application so both StoryBorad and LaunchScreen are important don't delete it.